# Thumb rotator by IMG URL folder location in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get folder location from IMG URL example https://cdn1.example.com/thumbs/23432/0.jpg via jQuery and to allow to set max images can be found on the folder example Total = 5 ( Images can be found in the folder URL).

The script after to generate the images URLs from the IMG URL example

```
https://cdn1.example.com/thumbs/23432/0.jpg
https://cdn1.example.com/thumbs/23432/1.jpg
https://cdn1.example.com/thumbs/23432/2.jpg
https://cdn1.example.com/thumbs/23432/3.jpg
https://cdn1.example.com/thumbs/23432/4.jpg
```

When a person hovers the "a link" with the mouse the image rotator to start with IMG 0.jpg ( First image from the list ) and END with 4.jpg

When the person remove the mouse from the a href to show the original image from `<img src="(original link)" />`.

I try some scripts but most of them need to add the links manually I was hoping I can find a script to work this way, and I see some issue with most thumb rotators, when they start to rotate some images is not fully loaded, I was hoping if there's a way to load images first before start rotate them.

HTML example:

```
<a href="/" class="video"><img src="https://cdn1.example.com/thumbs/23432/2.jpg" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var hoverstatus = false;
var imgArr = ["https://picsum.photos/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300"];

function imagehover() {
  hoverstatus = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
    var time = 1000 * (i + 1);
    changeImage(i, time);
  }
}

function changeImage(i, time) {
  if (hoverstatus == false) {
    imagehoverout();
    return;
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
    jQuery('.video img').attr('src', imgArr[i]);
  }, time);
}

function imagehoverout() {
  hoverstatus = false;
  $('.video img').attr('src', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/" class="video"><img onmouseover="imagehover()" onmouseout="imagehoverout()" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: Ty for the answer, but is not helping me with what i need ... i need a script to auto get the other images via img src="" ... the way your script is doing i need to add them via array, and i have multiple URLs ( thumbs ) per page ... this script will not help me fix what i need.

Comment: Updated. U have multiple image for array pass to 'imgArr '

Comment: Hello, it is still not what i need ... via your code, i need for each video thumb URL to create a new array ... i have over 40 images links that are meaning i need to create 40 arrays via jquery because this i need some code to match and replace the end URL and generate the extra URL images via https://cdn1.example.com/thumbs/23432/